# Debugging JS errors

Tags: javascript, debug

I'm struggling with this error and would appreciate some help.

Wordpress with the MasterStudy theme and then MasterStudy LMS plugin. Elementor on top. Everything up to date. I have a caching plugin, but it's deactivated. Cloudflare on top.

https://www.swingdancehome.com/en/all-courses/solo-jazz-english-spanish/

When I click on "Curriculum" I should see all the classes. Equally, when going back to "Overview" the content disappears as well.

I'm not an experienced coder yet, so struggling how I could fix this. I do see erros in the LMS plugin in the console though.

Any help or steps how to figure this out would be very welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like something is adding `/en/` to the beginning of the links on the tabs. If you're using a multi-language plugin there might be a compatibility issue with the MasterStudy plugin. You're going to need to speak to the developers of each plugin. It's not something that's fixable from here unless you're coding this yourself.

Comment: Indeed, I do have a translation plug-in that sets the "/en/" slug. Thank you for helping with this! Much appreciated.